# VSCode java debugger externalConsole

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm writing a java program which read inputs from console with VSCode. I tried debugging, but the debug console of VSCode does not accept inputs. After some googling, I found [`"externalConsole"` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688454/reading-input-during-debugging-in-python-with-vscode). However, it does not work - VSCode says that the property is not allowed. Is the java debugger of VSCode not available of this feature? If so, how can I work with VSCode?

Answer (score 4):

"externalConsole" option is deprecated. You can use the "console" option.

```
"console": "integratedTerminal"
```

console option:
It specifies console to launch the program. Defaults to internalConsole.

- internalConsole - VS Code Debug Console (input stream not supported).
- integratedTerminal - VS Code Integrated Terminal.
- externalTerminal - External terminal that can be configured in user settings.

Please refer vscode [debugging documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging) for more information. Should work for other languages also apart from Java if debugging is supported.