# External Terminal Debugger in VS Code

Tags: python, json, debugging, visual-studio-code

As I can't give input in the debug console, I'm trying to run the debugger in External terminal in VS Code.

This is the part of launch.json config file for external terminal.

```
{
            "name": "Python: Terminal (external)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "env": {},
            "externalConsole": true,
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit"
            ]
},
```

I added the `"externalConsole": true` part as they said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688454/reading-input-during-debugging-in-python-with-vscode#36781000) and I tried with or without that statement.

I get this error,

```
Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly
```

I tried the [docs](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387) and the IntelliSense in the json file, but I can't understand and get it to work.

Comment: I'm using linux btw, if that helps

Answer (score 5):

Adding `"console": "externalTerminal",` to the debug configuration file worked fine on Linux!

Answer (score 2):

I am using windows, however, this should fix your problem.

```
"name": "Python: Terminal (external)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "C:/Users/Zac/Anaconda3/python.exe",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "",
        "console": "externalTerminal",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
```

You need to correctly add a path to your python.exe location in the "pythonPath" line.

Also, take out the "WaitOnAbnormalExit" and "WaitOnNormalExit" from "debugOptions" and just use "RedirectOutput". Remove "externalConsole": true from the code.

Everything else should stay the same.

Hope that helps.
Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Also remember to put correct value for external terminal location in :

**terminal.external.windowsExec**