# How to provide input data while debugging in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I wanted to know that how can we provide data while debugging in VS Code. For eg.

```
a = input()
b = input()

c = a + b

print(c)
```

I also have a input.txt file as follows:

```
10
20
```

So when I run `python test.py < input.txt`, the code should read the data and run.

But while debugging how can I tell the debugger to use the input?

Comment: Have you tried sys.argv[ ] method for reading the file?

Comment: sys.argv would require me to open file and read line by line. Isn't there something similar to just doing python test.py < input.txt while debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Create a debugging configuration with`externalConsole": true`. Check [Igor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36781000/5159551)'s solution for more information. Reading input from a text file would not work for `input()` but instead you can provide as application parameters using `sys.argv[]`.

[image: screenshot of test code.]

here is when I run the code with external debugging.