# Python - EOF error on input only in Linux terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, eoferror

It is working in VS CODE terminal but not in linux terminal.ERROR:

```
File "/home/shaheer/start.py", line 10, in <module>
ques = input("Are you ready? (y/n)")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

MY CODE:

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from subprocess import DEVNULL
import webbrowser
import time

time.sleep(10)

ques = input("Are you ready? (y/n)")
if ques == "y":
  print("Good!")
elif ques == "Y":
  print("Good!")
else:
  cmd = "pkill chrome"
  Popen([cmd], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
```

I am making it as a reminder script for people who use their system for a long time.

Comment: Maybe this question is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688454/reading-input-during-debugging-in-python-with-vscode

Comment: that might be the problem with your terminal just use python3 <filename.py>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[UPDATE] it's now working, i had to make another .py file and link that to this one.
**file 1 (start.py):**

```
import os
os.system("python3 /home/shaheer/playsound.py")
```

**file 2 (playsound.py):**

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
from subprocess import DEVNULL
import webbrowser
import time

time.sleep(10)

ques = input("Are you ready? (y/n)")
if ques == "y":
  print("Good!")
elif ques == "Y":
  print("Good!")
else:
  cmd = "pkill chrome"
  Popen([cmd], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
```