# Input statement isn't evaluated during debugging - triggers a Try Except

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write a basic tic-tac-toe in Python. One of my functions is meant to get the user's input as a number from 1 to 9. If the user enters a non-integer, or a number not between 1 and 9, it will return an error. It's nestled in a try-except to avoid worrying about type conversion.

```
def get_move():
    print("Your move ...")

    while True:
        try:
            move = input("Type a number from 1-9: ")
            if move.isnumeric():
                if (0 < int(move) < 10):
                    break
                else:
                    print("The number is outside the range. Try again.")
            else:
                if (move.tolower == "quit") or (move.tolower == "exit"):
                    exit()
        except:
            print("Not a valid integer, try again.")

    return move
```

This sort-of works when I run normally. But when I try to debug in VS Code, when the debugger reaches the line `move = input("Type a number from 1-9: ")` and I click "Step Into", it simply goes straight to the "except" clause. And the code proceeds in an infinite loop - it will never stop and wait for the user input, meaning that I have to manually stop the debugger.

Any idea why it might be doing this?

**Edit:**

Thanks for correcting my typo, but that hasn't solved the problem. I've changed the line from:

```
if (move.tolower == "quit") or (move.tolower == "exit"):
    exit()
```

to:

```
if move.lower() == "quit" or move.lower() == "exit":
    exit()
```

And also changed the `except` clause to `except (ValueError, TypeError)`. Now I receive the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: EOFError
EOF when reading a line
  File "[...]tictacpy.py", line 18, in get_move
    move = input("Type a number from 1-9: ")
  File "[...]tictacpy.py", line 46, in <module>
    move = get_move()
```

Comment: Catch-all excepts are a bad idea, especially if they just discard the actual error. How do you know that the exception was caused by an invalid integer being entered? You should be catching specific errors, and the general catch-all `except` should give you some indication of what the actual underlying error was.

Comment: this issue is caused by `to_lower` (isn't a valid `str` attribute or method) - make it `if move.lower() == "quit" or move.lower() == "exit":`

Comment: To the close-vote "not reproducible or caused by a typo" - I've fixed the typo and the problem still isn't solved.

Comment: Also, I'd really appreciate if the downvoters could also clarify where the question needs improvement. How am I supposed to improve the question quality if you don't tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: Take a look at the questions in this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%5Bvscode%5D+input

Comment: Thanks Barmar, that lead me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36781000/1907765) which has seemed to solve my problem. I changed the value of "console" to "integratedTerminal" in the launch.json file. Now the debugger works!

Comment: ...Although now I have the issue that my debugger times out every other time I open it :/. I guess that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is happening because in the debugger you do not have a console for standard input, so calling `input()` will error (I don't know VS code specifically so I'm guessing here, but this is a reasonable cause).

In any case, I'd strongly suggest not using all-catching `except` clauses as this silences and wrongly handles errors that may happen that are *not* a part of your expected flow.

I'd start by changing your `except` to say `except (ValueError, TypeError)` so that it only catches errors resulting from bad input / type conversion issues. You'll then be able to see what the real error is.

Also, note that there is no such thing as `move.tolower` - you probably meant `move.lower()`. Maybe that's your bug?

Comment: Thanks, I was carrying syntax from Visual Basic with the `tolower`. I'm still getting an error though - I've changed the Except clause as you suggested, and now the debugger returns `Exception has occurred: EOFError
EOF when reading a line
  File "...tictacpy.py", line 18, in get_move
    move = input("Type a number from 1-9: ")
  File "...tictacpy.py", line 46, in <module>
    move = get_move()`

Comment: Yep, pretty sure that means stdin has ended / closed in your debugger. Figure out how to get vscode to let you type in standard input.